# Spring Security Case Sensitive

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

My MySql database is case sensitive, everything works fine in hibernate, table name in the data base are the same of my classes. But on Spring Security, the default authentication doesn't work well, building the SQL with the first letter of the table name with lower case instead of upper case. Is there any way to make spring security understand upper case like hibernate does? Or Do I need to build a custom authentication only to change the table name to capital letter?

```
<!-- Session Factory Hibernate -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.empresa.domain" />
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="mySQLdataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <!-- Novos geradores de ids recomendados pela documentação do hibernate -->
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<!-- Conexão com o Banco de Dados -->
<bean id="mySQLdataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" />    --> 
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="asd123456" />

</bean>

<!-- It is responsible for validating the user's credentials -->
<security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- It is responsible for providing credential validation to the AuthenticationManager -->
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="mySQLdataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"
    id="passwordEncoder" />
```

Comment: how does spring security access database? how did you configured?

Comment: @Kent added my configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you use **JdbcDaoImpl** (via **jdbc-user-service** element). If it's true then you can provide your own SQL for default queries.

```
<jdbc-user-service 
    users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from Users where username = ?" 
    authorities-by-username-query="select username, authority from Authorities where username = ?" 
/>
```

Comment: And if you need the user name to be case-insensitive then simply use a native function like `lower()` (or `upper()`) in the `WHERE` clause like `where lower(username) = lower(?)`.

Comment: @Maksym Demidas That's exactaly the way I found on Internet, that's fine, but why Spring Security doesn't behave like hibernate? I put the @Table(name="Users") annotation. Anyway, Spring should have a better integration with hibernate, then the annotation should be enough.

Comment: Because Spring Security must work even without Hibernate. So **JdbcDaoImpl** use plain JDBC calls instead of Hibernate. If you want, you can provide your own DAO that implements UserDetailsService and that use Hibernate. Spring Security will be able to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried the configuration above, it's more accurate that the ones I found on Internet. After some advices, I decide to change the case sensitive option on MySql. The lower_case_table_names variable on my.ini on mysql root directory. I just put lower_case_table_names=1 and the problem is gone, now MySql is case insensitive.